Equivocal numbers : A base system question
Caltech Harvey Mudd Mathematics Competition ( CHMMC ) $2012$ Team Round Problem $7$ :

A positive integer $x$ is $k$-equivocal if there exists two positive integers $b$, $b’$ such that when $x$ is represented in base $b$ and base $b’$, the two representations have digit sequences of length $k$ that
are permutations of each other.
The smallest $2$-equivocal number is $7$, since $7$ is $21$ in base $3$ and $12$ in base $5$.
Find the smallest $3$-equivocal number.

In this question, $22$ was given as the answer in the official solution and then it was proved that no number less than $22$ will satisfy the given conditions.
The method with which they reached $22$ was not given.
So, is there any way other than hit and trial to get the desired answer ?

What have you tried? In this forum, you're expected to share your own work in order to get help.

What was the proof, maybe that can give you some insights on how they reached to $22$ in the first place

Once you eliminate $2$ as a possible base, you can remark that $101_4=17$ is the least possible candidate.  After that, the search does not take long.

Let the bases be $a$ and $b$ and the number be $n$. WLOG let $b>a$. Then we have $a^2<n<a^3$ and $b^2<n<b^3$. Then $a^2<b^3$ and $b^2<a^3$. You can check that $b=4$ and $a=3$ are the least permissible solutions. Then $16<n<64$ and $9<n<27$ etc, where you have small ranges to check.
